# How to build the browser extension with substrate?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, signed-extensions, browser-extension

Can we make browser extension with substrate and yes and how ?

can anyone please provide the resource to read about it ?

Comment: do you mean you want to fork the polkadot-js extension? Or do you mean you want to interact with the extension?

Comment: Have a look at smoldot https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot

Comment: @Decentration Actually I want to built my own custom extrinsic with substrate. can I do it ?

Comment: you can do it for sure, i guess you just need to start somewhere simple to develop the learning and practice to get into a feedback loop. Best place to start is the https://substrate.dev exercises related to setting up local chain. Then to make an extrinsic you would need to create your own pallet. This takes some learning time and practice if you are new to it. Between 6 to 18 months is a rough guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
You can take a look for inspiration of two of the most populars browser extensions [PolkadotJS Extension](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension) and [Talisman](https://github.com/TalismanSociety/talisman-web).

To build it yourself and connect to Substrate-base chains in a decentralized way, I recommend you to use the package [Substrate Connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@substrate/connect)

> For Substrate-based chains, the light client node is implemented as a
> WebAssembly client—called smoldot—that can run in a browser and
> interact with the chain using JSON-RPC calls. To make the smoldot
> WebAssembly light client easier to integrate with JavaScript and
> TypeScript applications, there's a JavaScript package that's built on
> top of the smoldot source called Substrate Connect.

For more information you can:

- Read the documentation [Light clients in Substrate Connect](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/light-clients-in-substrate-connect/)
- Do the Tutorial [Integrate a light client node](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/integrate-a-light-client-node/) where it shows you  how to use the Substrate Connect browser extension to interact with the blockchain directly without using an intermediary node or RPC server.
- Check the code of the [Substrate Connect examples](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/tree/main/projects).